# Will fatal exceptions still allow a catch/finally to execute

Tags: c#, try-catch, fatal-error, try-catch-finally

Im wondering if when a fatal exception occurs in a try block which I cannot handle (`OutOfMemory` for example) will it still be able to send a notification in catch/finally block to tell me that the console application has stopped?

if not, what would be the proper way to send a notification in case of a fatal error?

Comment: That isn't a fatal exception, just one that usually cannot be handled correctly.

Comment: If a catch/finally would still execute, it woult not be a fatal exception.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly so there is no way to still send a notification in case of a fatal error?

Comment: In my understanding a fatal (deadly) error is an error that causes the program to abort. Since the program is no longer executing it cannot possibly do anything (like sending a notification). However there could be a wrapper task that notices the error and sends a notification. But if that task has a fatal error then you are having the same problem one floor above. If the PC explodes nothing is going to send any notifications from that PC. But it could have been monitored by another PC which can send a notification. And so on. It is better to accept that some things are beyond control. :-)